# How to display data of a table in a specific pattern in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I  have a table with three columns and 500 rows. I need to display data of this table in a particular pattern in another table.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3 

Item1   Item2   Item3 

Item4   Item5   Item6
```

Output to be displayed in following pattern-

```
item1 item2 item3

item2 item1 item3

item3 item1 item2

item4 item5 item6

item5 item4 item6

item6 item4 item5
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Since SQL sets are unordered, you can try:

```
WITH Source AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'),
    ('Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6')) T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Source
UNION ALL
SELECT Col2, Col1, Col3 FROM Source
UNION ALL
SELECT Col3, Col1, Col2 FROM Source
```

If you need to keep ordering, see following query:

```
WITH Source AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) GroupNumber FROM (VALUES
    ('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'),
    ('Item4', 'Item5', 'Item6')) T(Col1, Col2, Col3)
),Numbered AS
(
    SELECT GroupNumber, 1 SecondaryGroup, Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Source
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GroupNumber, 2, Col2, Col1, Col3 FROM Source
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GroupNumber, 3, Col3, Col1, Col2 FROM Source
)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Numbered ORDER BY GroupNumber, SecondaryGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

this solves your problem.

```
Create table #temp (one nvarchar(50),two nvarchar(50), three nvarchar(50))  -- Source Table 
Create table #temptarget (one nvarchar(50),two nvarchar(50), three nvarchar(50)) -- Target Table
Insert into #temp -- Insert into Source Table. already you have
values('item1','item2','item3')
Insert into #temp
values('item4','item5','item6')
Insert into #temp
values('item7','item8','item9')

Declare @RowCount AS INT
Declare @currRowIndex AS INT = 1 -- Current Row Index
select @RowCount = COUNT(*) from #temp --  No Of Rows

WHILE (@currRowIndex <= @RowCount)
BEGIN -- Insert into target table
Insert into #temptarget 
select t.one, t.two,t.three from
(select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order By one) AS RNo,* from #temp) t Where t.RNo = @currRowIndex
UNION
select t.two, t.one,t.three from
(select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order By one) AS RNo,* from #temp) t Where t.RNo = @currRowIndex
UNION
select t.three, t.one,t.two from
(select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order By one) AS RNo,* from #temp) t Where t.RNo = @currRowIndex
SET @currRowIndex +=1
END
SELECT * FROM #temptarget
```